# Can not get .Trash-1000 working on NTFS auto mount?

Tags: ntfs, fstab, trash

I am using fstab to automount a NTFS dive... but I can not get the trash folder to work....

The line when I auto mount in `fstab` is:

```
/dev/sdc1 /media/Data ntfs-3g defaults,uid-1000,locale=en_US.utf8 0 2
```

My user ID is 1000 when I do `id -u USERNAME`.

I have tried to make a dir called `.Trash-1000` and also tried `.Trash` on the root of the NTFS drive... and I `chmod`ed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `uid-1000`. It should be `uid=1000`.